# How to continue markdown bullet text after sub bullets are inserted

Tags: markdown

Question on Markdown. What is the best way to continue a point after defining some sub-points? In the example below, 'and that concluded point 1' will lose the indentation of the list. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

```
This is the primary text and I need some bullets:

  1. This is the first point. The first point has some sub-points:
    a. sub-point a
    b. sub-point b
and that concluded point 1
  2. This is the second point
```

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the markdown engine you're using, how many spaces you're indenting with, and whether you're using blank lines between items.

When I preview this:

```
This is the primary text and I need some bullets:

1. This is the first point. The first point has some sub-points:

      a. sub-point a

      b. sub-point b

      and that concluded point 1

2. This is the second point
```

on https://markdownlivepreview.com/, it shows up correctly:

[image]

Similar rendering on https://dillinger.io:
[image]

Although they seem to render as HTML.